# in next.js 14 how to pass data from one page to another without showing data on url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am a React Native dev trying to build a web app my quastion is in next.js 14 how to pass data from one page to another without showing data on url? I have an app directory in my Next.js project.

by not showing data on URL i mean for example http://localhost:3000/mypage?name="Johndeo"

I have a Button component that I am using in my whole app for Button. it also has a href prop for navigating from one page to another.

i want to access pass name as data from page1 and log it to page2

This is how i am using Button component
`<Button href="/mypage2">     Go to page2 </Button>`

Buttom component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link'
import clsx from 'clsx'

interface ButtonProps {
  type?: "button" | "submit" | "reset";
  href?: string;
  className?: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export function Button({ href, className, children, ...props }: ButtonProps) {

  className = clsx(
    className,
    'inline-flex rounded-full px-4 py-1.5 text-sm font-semibold transition bg-white text-black hover:bg-neutral-200'
  )

  let inner = <span className="relative top-px">{children}</span>

  if (href) {
    return (
      <Link href={href} className={className} {...props}>
        {inner}
      </Link>
    )
  }

  return (
    <button className={className} {...props}>
      {inner}
    </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: I‘d use either the browser's`localStorage` to persist data or use a global in memory store like `Zustand` or `Redux` if you can navigate the pages with the nextjs router. (All client side) if you instead have to use server side rendering use headers or Cookies

Comment: @wavedeck Yes, But it's not a better solution, because  -if you have an app where you are fetching a bunch of users' profiles and letting users to click on each profile and check its details storing data is not a better solution

Comment: Okay with that context in mind i‘d either do dynamic routes eg. navigating from `/users` to `/users/:id` so you can fetch the details serverside or just do client side rendering. I‘ll write out two solutions one in csr and one via dynamic routes if that help

Comment: Make sense. But it will take time to get a response server. I think Next.js can navigate from one page to another with data without any issues.

Comment: pressing a button on the client is decoupled from the server so you need to pass the data somehow (cookies, headers, query, params...) so client side rendering (with 'use client') is probably your only practical option if you really want to not change the url. In CSR it would be as easy as passing the user details as component props to the UserDetail component and displaying it. Keep in mind however that this will result in a larger bundle size for that specific page.

Comment: Yep, But in my case the profile only contains a name, caption, and a profileimage URL. So is whats the best way?  for URL i mean i don't want URL like this http://localhost:3000/mypage?name="Johndeo". but i want URL like http://localhost:3000/mypage

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use server side rendering in Next.js, you need to keep in mind that actions happening on the client side (clicking a button) are decoupled from the server and since HTTP is by definition a stateless protocol, you have to pass data either via cookies, headers or use query parameters such as `/users?user=USERNAME`. Alternatively, you can also use dynamic routes in Next.js to format it more nicely like `/users/:id` but the concept is essentially the same.

If you however can't pass data to the server you can fall back to client side rendering with `'use client'` as the first line of the component file and conditionally fetch / render the data on the client using javascript.

Here is an example using client side rendering, where i assumed that the details were already available to the page. Otherwise you'd have to pass some identifier (e.g. username) to the UserDetails component and fetch the details from there.

page.jsx:

```jsx
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

// Let's assume this is the data you get from the API
const userInfo = [
  {
    name: "John Doe",
    caption: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    profileImg: "https://images.example.com/users/john-doe.jpg",
  },
  ... // more users go here
];

// User details modal
// I assumed you want to show the details as a popup modal when the user clicks on the button
// and close the modal when the user clicks outside the modal
export const UserDetails = ({ user, setUserDetails }) => {
  const closeModal = () => {
    setUserDetails(null);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="backdrop" onClick={closeModal}>
        <div className="modal">
          <img src={user.profileImg} alt={user.name} />
          <h1>{user.name}</h1>
          <p>{user.caption}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

// Main Page component
// It renders the list of users and renders the UserDetails component conditionally
// when the user clicks on the button and hides it when the userDetails state is null again
export default function Home() {
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = (user) => {
    setUserDetails(user);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* Display the list of users */}
      {userInfo.map((user) => (
        <ul>
          <li>
            {user.name}
            <button onClick={() => handleClick(user)}>Show Details</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      ))}
      {/* Conditionally display UserDetails when the state is set */}
      {userDetails && (
        <UserDetails
          user={userDetails} // pass the user details to the modal
          setUserDetails={setUserDetails} // pass the setUserDetails function to the modal
                                          // so we can reset the state from within the modal
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: How to do with the next.js Link component

Comment: The Link component cannot pass state so you‘d have to implement the way i‘ve described for server side rendering.

Comment: E.g. pass a id in the url and fetch the user details from the target page using the id. There is no practical other way using SSR since you will loose state scoped to the last page. The last resort would be using global state such as react context, zustand or redux and render the details page as a client component since nextjs (server) has no access to it. But then you’ll loose all advantages of using Nextjs (SSR) and could just create a CSR project using vite and react-router

Comment: Also keep in mind that using the nextjs router (<Link>) will result in a URL change which would be against your requirement to not change the url

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I understand how i need to navigate to a whole page